# How to hide bot /command message in telegram group?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I created a bot added to a private group read/comment only for users, as admin I don’t want users to see /command message when I use a bot function, is it possible? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFpCl.jpg)

Using a private chat 1:1 with the bot defeats our purposes and the same using a bot webpage to send the message in the group affects ux

Answer (score 0):

If bot is chat admin, you can delete messages with commands (by bot).
Not the best solution, but it's a little time gap when users can see your command.